# nicer ticks for logarithmic Axes3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

creating a log Axes3D object is an issue (see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209))

a workaround is

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

ax.plot_surface(x, y, np.log10(z))

def log_tick_formatter(val, pos=None):
    return "{:.2e}".format(10**val)

ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(log_tick_formatter))
```

this produces zticks of the form 1.0e-5.
How should I modify it to have ticks of the (LaTeX)
form 10^{-5} (as in standard logplots)?

Here is a minimal example to play with. Many thanks in advance!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection="3d")
x = np.arange(5+1)
y = np.arange(6+1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.zeros(X.shape)
for ii in x:
    for jj in y:
        Z[jj, ii] = -min(ii, jj) 
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
ax.view_init(elev=10, azim=-45)
def log_tick_formatter(val, pos=None):
    return "{:.0e}".format(10**val)
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(log_tick_formatter))
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following format:

```
def log_tick_formatter(val, pos=None):
    return r"$10^{{{:.0f}}}$".format(val)
```

but be aware that this - just like your solution - only works, if ticks are accidentally placed at whole numbers.